# Disable autoscroll on TextInput focus inside a ScrollView on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I was trying to accomplish what was asked in this question here on react-native repo, but it was auto-closed - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19995

I have `<TextInput>` in a `<ScrollView>` and keyboard mode is "resize" in android manifest (i need to keep it at resize). When focusing an input that is not totally in view, Android scrolls the scrollview to it. I want to disable this behavior, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try with [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview)

I usually use the code something like below

```
 <ThemeConsumer>
        {({ theme }) => (
          <ThemedView isFullView>
            <Header
              leftComponent={<IconHeader />}
              centerComponent={<TextHeader title={t('common:text_forgot')} />}
            />
            <ScrollView>
              <KeyboardAvoidingView>
                <Container>
                  <Text style={styles.description} colorSecondary>
                    {t('auth:text_description_forgot')}
                  </Text>
                  {message ? (
                    <TextHtml value={message} style={changeColor(theme.colors.error)} />
                  ) : null}
                  <Input
                    label={t('auth:text_input_email')}
                    value={email}
                    onChangeText={value => this.setState({ email: value })}
                    error={errors && errors.email}
                  />
                  <Button
                    title={t('common:text_submit')}
                    containerStyle={styles.margin}
                    loading={pendingForgotPassword}
                    onPress={this.handleSubmit}
                  />
                </Container>
              </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </ScrollView>
          </ThemedView>
        )}
      </ThemeConsumer>
```

Comment: Thank you, KeyboardAvoidingView is cool, but in my case I'm specifically not needing any keyboard avoiding.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` however, when tapping `<TextInput>` it is still scrolling to it. Are you sure your solution works?